# call phone by clicking on number in web

Tags: asterisk, pbx, elastix

Im newbie from asterisk but professional in PHP programming!, so
I want to call mobile number in my users panel in web. exactly when user click on a number, connect to asterisk and call selected mobile number via specified internal extension.
is there any solution? I don't know about using any softphone or not. I don't want to use any client softphone if possible.

edit:

I used some php code with AMI and shift8, but my problem is when user calling and how can user talk with another without softphone?

Answer (score 1):

You can use various API's to place a phone call. As you already learned about the AMI you might find http://code.google.com/p/asterisk-php-api/ helpful.

Regarding your phone question: placing a phone call using the [AMI Originate Action](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Manager+API+Action+Originate) will first ring the extension's associated phone and when you take of the hook, asterisk will dial the target number. Therefore it's not importent which kind of phone (hard- or softphone, brand, ...) you're using. As long as the phone is registered in asterisk and bound to a certain extension it'll work.

Comment: I just want to using an interface on web. I mean when asterisk calling to my number, so how can speack with another on web. is there any web interface softphone or I have to use desktop softphone if possible

Comment: sorry, i got your question completely wrong. So you're searching for some web integrated phone solution to talk right "into your browser" ? I don't know of such a project but i guess it should be possible with flash or html5 (for some browsers). A quick google reveals http://code.google.com/p/sipml5/ (HTML5) and http://code.google.com/p/red5phone/ (flash based) to me, take a look at those, maybe it helps to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the doddle [web phone](http://www.doddlephone.com/) or [webrtc](http://www.webrtc.org/) may be an example of what your looking for.